# Django formset validating excluded field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

So I have a formset which I'm trying to populate form a `post`. The problem I'm running into is that when I do `is_valid()` on my formset, it fails and gives me a `MultiValueDictKeyError` for a field which I don't have included.

This is my form:

```
class ModbusRegistersForm(ModelForm):
    ixIOType = ModelChoiceField(queryset=IOType.objects.all())
    ixIOType.widget = Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-form': '0'})

    bRange = BooleanField(required=False)
    bRange.widget.attrs['data-form'] = 0

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['sRegisterName','iStartingAddr','bRange','ixIOType','iOffset']
        widgets = {
                'sRegisterName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Register Name','class': 'form-control', 'data-form': '0'}),
                'iStartingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Starting address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
                'iOffset': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address offset','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
            }
```

My view:

```
RegisterFormset = modelformset_factory(Register, form=ModbusRegistersForm)


prefix = request.POST['prefix_num']
if request.method == 'POST':
    registers = RegisterFormset(QueryDict(request.POST['form']), prefix='register_' + prefix)

    for reg in registers.forms:#fails on this line
        if reg.is_valid():
```

when the user clicks on save, i post to the server along with the prefix of the chosen form and the form itself using ajax. In my view I get the prefix  and populate my formset with the `POST` data. However when it hits the line `for reg in registers.forms:` it throws an error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError("u'register_2-0-ixRegister'",)   MultiValueDictKeyError
```

what I don't understand is that ixRegister isn't even specified in my form, so why is my formset trying to access it if I've given it the post data?

Comment: You need to exclude the fields that are not going to be filled by the user in the form: So in your `class Meta` replace `fields =...` with  something like`exclude = ('ixRegister')`

Comment: I've tested it before with the exclude and it still tries to validate tht field. I have no clue where it's even getting the field from when I'm passing it data